# Make PHP wait for each MySql query to excecute

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run multiple mysql queries from one php page but I need it to "wait" until each query is finished before moving on. It seems that at the moment it will load them all at the same time.

Is there a work around for this or a function to make the page wait until the query is done before going to the next one?

--edited--

so here is my code

```
//These top three seem to work fine but I guess it doesn't matter if the next one starts before the last one ends
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE\n".
"FROM\n".
"   temp_cats");
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE\n".
"FROM\n".
"   temp_concats");
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE\n".
"FROM\n".
"   temp_locations");
```

That seems to work OK but I wouldn't notice if one starts before the one before ends.

The next query works fine. It takes countrys mentioned in the query from another table and adds it to a new table. The update query "labels" them in another column.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE temp_locations (temp_locations.Location) SELECT DISTINCT\n".
"Region\n".
"FROM\n".
"LocationsForExcel\n".
"WHERE\n".
"Country IN (" . $_SESSION['SearchCountriesQuery'] . ")");
//mark the new locations type as country
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE temp_locations\n".
"SET LocationType = 'Country'\n".
"WHERE\n".
"   LocationType IS NULL");
```

The problems come when I put this underneath:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE temp_locations (temp_locations.Location) SELECT DISTINCT\n".
"Region\n".
"FROM\n".
"LocationsForExcel\n".
"WHERE\n".
"Country IN" . $_SESSION['SearchCountriesQuery'] . ")");
//mark the new locations type as region
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE temp_locations\n".
"SET LocationType = 'Region'\n".
"WHERE\n".
"   LocationType IS NULL");
```

The end result is that both of the INSERT queries are running fine but the 'LocationType' column are all showing as 'Country'.

The only thing that I can think is happening is that the queries are not running in order or are over lapping each other.

Does anyone see whats going on here?

Comment: Show some code where you have them all running at the same time.  The default is for code to run one line at a time, so if you are accidentally bypassing this... confused.

Comment: I have just added the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not** a realy good method of doing it but what you could to is this (Showing some code would help a lot):

```
<?php
$query = //your query

if($query) {
 $query2 = //your 2nd query
}

if($query2) {
 $query3 = //your 3rd query
}
//and so on
?>
```